# Create custom groups on columns and count another column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server and I have a table named Table that looks like this.

| SenderId | ReciverId | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 |

I want to make groups of the SenderIds and ReciverIds. Then I would like to total the ItemCount between those groups. The Groupings would be as follows.

SenderId 1 = First. SenderIds 2,3 = Second. SenderIds = 4,5,6 = Third
ReciverId 1 = First. ReciverIds 2,3 = Second. ReciverIds = 4,5,6 = Third

I want to return the following

| SenderGroup | ReceiverGroup | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | First | 0 |
| First | Second | 5 |
| First | Third | 7 |
| Second | First | 3 |
| Second | Second | 0 |
| Second | Third | 6 |
| Third | First | 0 |
| Third | Second | 13 |
| Third | Third | 15 |

I've tried a few different queries without much success. Here's some of what I have so far.

```
SELECT 'First' AS SenderGroup, COUNT(ItemCount) AS ItemCount
FROM Table
WHERE SenderId IN (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the exact result you are expecting, you can use a cte to first build the custom group and then create fetch the related data from  your table joining with cte.

A query will be something like

```
with dummyMap AS (
  select 1 as id, 'First' as des UNION ALL 
  select 2, 'Second' UNION ALL 
  select 3, 'Second' UNION ALL 
  select 4, 'Third' UNION ALL 
  select 5, 'Third' UNION ALL 
  select 6, 'Third' 
)
select  sndrMap.des 'SenderGroup', rcvrMap.des 'ReceiverGroup', sum(isnull(ItemCount,0)) 'ItemCount'
from dummyMap sndrMap 
cross join dummyMap rcvrMap 
left join <your-table> on ReciverId = rcvrMap.id and SenderId = sndrMap.id
group by sndrMap.des, rcvrMap.des 
order by 
    case sndrMap.des when 'First' then 1 when 'Second' then 2 else 3 end asc, 
    case rcvrMap.des when 'First' then 1 when 'Second' then 2 else 3 end asc
```

**[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d1852f29b763ad5ad284a04bd6267fc)** is a fiddle

Comment: A `VALUES` table constructor would be simpler than `UNION ALL` eg `with dummyMap AS (select * FROM (1, 'First'), (2, 'Second'), ..... ) v(id, des) )`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a least/greatest trick here, then aggregate by sender and receiver and find the counts:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN SenderId < ReciverId
                THEN SenderId ELSE ReciverId END AS SenderGroup,
           CASE WHEN SenderId < ReciverId
                THEN ReciverId ELSE SenderId END AS ReceiverGroup,
           ItemCount
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT SenderGroup, ReceiverGroup, SUM(ItemCount) AS ItemCount
FROM cte
GROUP BY SenderGroup, ReceiverGroup;
```

### Demo

Comment: This doesn't create the custom groups of the SenderIds and ReciverIds I need.